# <script> code in Meteor runs fine but exact code moved to .onRendered() doesn't

Tags: meteor, cincopa

I'm really confused about this. I'm using Cincopa to create and embed image galleries onto my Meteor site.

This works. The gallery shows up on page load.:

```
<template name="test">

  <!-- Image Gallery Embed Code -->_

  <div id="cp_widget_a718e3a7-4a35-4f13-b14e-299cc73c6ecb">...</div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  var cpo = [];
  cpo["_object"] = "cp_widget_a718e3a7-4a35-4f13-b14e-299cc73c6ecb";
  cpo["_fid"] = "A4IAkTttPOWL";
  var _cpmp = _cpmp || [];
  _cpmp.push(cpo);
  (function() {
    var cp = document.createElement("script");
    cp.type = "text/javascript";
    cp.async = true;
    cp.src = "//www.cincopa.com/media-platform/runtime/libasync.js";
    var c = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    c.parentNode.insertBefore(cp, c);
  })();
  </script>

  <!-- Image Gallery Embed Code -->_

</template>
```

This does not. Nothing but the empty `<div>` with `...` shows up. There are no error messages.

```
<template name="test">

  <div id="cp_widget_a718e3a7-4a35-4f13-b14e-299cc73c6ecb">...</div>

</template>
```

JS:

```
Template.test.onRendered(function(){

  var cpo = [];
  cpo["_object"] = "cp_widget_a718e3a7-4a35-4f13-b14e-299cc73c6ecb";
  cpo["_fid"] = "A4IAkTttPOWL";
  var _cpmp = _cpmp || [];
  _cpmp.push(cpo);
  (function() {
    var cp = document.createElement("script");
    cp.type = "text/javascript";
    cp.async = true;
    cp.src = "//www.cincopa.com/media-platform/runtime/libasync.js";
    var c = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    c.parentNode.insertBefore(cp, c);
  })();

});
```

It's the exact same code...

Am I missing something with how Meteor loads things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### EDIT

You need to make those variables available in the global scope for the script to access them:

Change

```
var _cpmp = _cpmp || [];
```

Remove the 'var' keyword and use window instead

```
window._cpmp = window._cpmp || [];
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the case. `document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]` is looking for the `first` `<script>` tag in the document, hence the `[0]`. It can be anything. Plus there already is a `<script>` tag.

Comment: Yeah, `var c = document.getElementById("cp_widget_a718e3a7-4a35-4f13-b14e-299cc73c6ecb");` doesn't work. I think they're using `var c  = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];` simply as an anchor so that `c.parentNode` is the `<head>` tag. In the working example in my OP, `c  = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]` is just some random Meteor `<script>` tag, completely unrelated to the photo gallery stuff.

Comment: Updated my answer @fuzzybabybunny

Comment: `_cpmp = _cpmp || [];` returns a `_cpmp is not defined` error.

Comment: Try `window._cpmp = window._cpmp || [];`

Comment: Ok, that works. I'm not sure why though. The `libasync.js` code that Cincopa provides has `var _cpmp = _cpmp || [];` as the first instance where `_cpmp` appears. So basically it's setting `_cpmp` as the current value of the global variable `_cpmp`, OR, if it's undefined, as an empty array?

Comment: The Cinpopa library is lazy loaded.The library is loaded after and looks for this variable in case there is a previous definition (such as a run of onRendered twice). When you use `var _cpmp` it runs this statement before it looks at the statement after the equals sign so thats '_cpmp'. Just removing `var` is not that simple and I didn't realize it, using `window` provides the same effect as global scoping, without the use of `var`. The original edit was a mistake on my part for not taking this into account.

Comment: Why would I need to make the `_cpmp` outside the `<script>` tags into a global variable in order for the script to access it, while inside of the `<script>` tags using `var` is ok? I'm guessing that there's some kind of special variable scoping for variables declared in `<script>` tags or something?

Comment: Yes using `var` in a script tag places it in the global context, using `var` in a `function(){..}` of any sort scopes it so that it can't be accessed outside of the `function(){..}` block, such as the onRendered one. This was the original issue that stopped it working. If you declared the variables in `<script>` they would not run in this scope and it would 'just work'. Every file in a meteor app is placed in a `function(){..}` block effectively giving alot of meaning to the use of the `var` keyword.